# How to check if a mousemove event has been triggered in 1 second

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a `canvas` element and a `div.coordinates` element that follows the mouse around when the mouse moves on the canvas. What I am trying to do is make the `.coordinates` disappear if the mouse hasn't been moving on the canvas in the last 1 second.

## HTML

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

## CSS

```
canvas {
  max-width: auto;
  outline: 1px solid #283028;
  align-self: center;
}

.coordinates {
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

## JS

```
let coordinates = document.createElement("div");
coordinates.className = "coordinates";


let time = undefined;
const trackCanvasMouse = (e) => {
  if (!time) {
    time = Date.now();
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (time == Date.now()) {
      coordinates.style.display = "none";
      time = undefined;
    }
  }, 1000);
  coordinates.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
  coordinates.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
  coordinates.style.display = "inline";
};

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", trackCanvasMouse);

canvas.width = 520;
canvas.height = 520;


document.querySelector("body").appendChild(coordinates);
```

I tried using `Time.now()` and `setTimeout` to see if an event has been triggered, but couldn't make it work.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show a span coords while the mouse is moving and disapear after the mouse stops for a second. What you want to do is keep track of the previous timeout and cancel it each time the mousemove event fires.

```js
let timeout;
const coords = document.getElementById('coords');
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
  coords.style.display = "block";
  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    coords.style.display = "none";
  }, 1000)
});
```

```css
#coords {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="coords">Coords</span>
```